# Bulk Redirect WordPress Posts to Category based URL after Permalink Structure is Changed

Tags: functions, permalinks, redirect, wp-redirect

```
function custom_category_redirect() {
    // Get the requested URL
    $requested_url = esc_url_raw(add_query_arg(array()));
    
    // Get the permalink structure
    $permalink_structure = get_option('permalink_structure');
    
    // Check if the requested URL is a bare URL (no path after the domain)
    if (empty(parse_url($requested_url, PHP_URL_PATH))) {
        // Get the category to redirect to based on the new permalink structure
        $category_slug = ''; // Set the default category slug
        if ($permalink_structure && preg_match('/%category%/', $permalink_structure)) {
            // Get the category based on the current URL
            $category_obj = get_term_by('slug', $category_slug, 'category');
            if ($category_obj instanceof WP_Term) {
                // Get the category ID and construct the new category-based URL
                $category_id = $category_obj->term_id;
                $category_url = get_category_link($category_id);
                
                // Redirect to the category-based URL
                wp_redirect($category_url, 301);
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'custom_category_redirect');
```

**Details:**

### Previous Permalink Structure:

[image]

### Now Permalink Structure:

[image]

**Issue:** I tried many Plugins to direct old URLs in bulk to the new `/%category%/%postname%/` then I wrote a function, but still it doesn't work. How should I resolve the issue corroding my existence?